# Div background color not showing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am starting from the body tag.

```
<body>
<div align="centre">
<header>

</header>

<section class="wrapper">

</section>

</div>

</body>
```

This is the basic structure of the page, the main problem is the section class="wrapper" is not loading its body-color which is set to white.

This is the CSS for the wrapper class.

```
.wrapper {
background: #FFF;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This is the link : http://codomotive.in/projects/classified/index1%20-%20Copy.html

All of it is working fine in CHROME, MOZILLA, SAFARI, but i have to make it working for IE8.
PLS HELP.

Comment: IE8 does not speak HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Diodeus, IE 8 does not natively support the newer HTML 5 tags (such as `<section>`).

You can, however, easily add the support using [html5shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv). **html5shiv** will enable support for those elements both in JavaScript (e.g., `document.getElementsByTagName('section')`) and in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you incorporate the [**HTML5 Shiv**](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to support IE8?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and lower need adding some code to support new html5 elements (suach as header, section etc.) :

```
<script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

Comment: I can't recommend this. It may be short, but doesn't fix *all* the bugs. I recommend using the full html5shiv script rather than this short one, otherwise you'll still have issues with stuff like dynamic elements and printing.

Comment: Yeah, and sometimes html5shiv really mess up your other javascripts - as it was in my case..

Answer (score 0):

Diodeus is correct, IE8 doesn't know what to do with . To get around this, insert an HTML shim. It's a javascript library that will allow legacy browsers to understand the  tag.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

More info here: https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Answer (score 0):

`header` and `section` are HTML5 tags. You need to include `html5shiv script` (https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to get HTML5 working on IE8

Also `centre` is illegal value for attribute `align`. You mean `center` here.

Besides that, since you are using HTML5 anyway, you should avoid `align` attribute entirely and use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not recognise new HTML5 tags like `<header>` and `<section>` as being valid. It will therefore not render them correctly.

You can fix this by using a hack called [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), which forces IE8 to recognise these tags.

Another option is to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which includes the same functionality, plus a bit more for helping you deal with other issues caused by using an old browser.